Manas Chittha and Buddhi
I am given to understand that sensory perceptions received from the Manas are compared by the Buddhi with the impressions, memories and experiences saved in Chittha and when there is a match, the buddhi instructs the Manas to set in motion the desired organs of actions as required.
What happens when the Buddhi receives a sensory perception that it has never received before?
